# Can String.format cause performance issues in this case?

Tags: java, performance

I made a change in our code. 
Original code:

```
private static String myStr = "Hello, this is a long sentence and it is about 400 words in total.  Read at your own risk.  Thanks.";
```

New code:

```
private static String myStr = String.format("Hello, this is a long sentence and it is about 400 words in total.%nRead at your own risk.%nThanks.");
```

The String.format was added ONLY for the purpose of line separators (%n). I am seeing our performance numbers go slightly worse but I can't tell if this is the culprit or if some other changes in the code are.

I believe this piece is instantiated just once in the entire run.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not `"... Read at your own risk.\r\nThanks."'? or `"...\n..."`?

Comment: Because that prints it out in the text file as ...Read at your own risk.\nThanks.  It did not add the line breaks. Hence, String.format.

Answer (score 3):

```
private static String myStr
```

Means it happens once. So no. Calling `String.format` will **not** hurt performance measurably. You **could** also possibly mark this as `final`. Which *might* help performance. But probably won't.

Comment: @Adam It tells the JIT (and compiler) that `myStr` won't change after declaration. It's possible (for example) that the compiler can then workout constant propagation for the field (probably not here though).

Comment: Thank you all.  I did not type it correctly. The variable is private final static String.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thank you for your detailed and clear explanation